# How to create modules while using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarqube5.6

I am trying to analyze a complex code which include C# and C++ segments, earlier when I was using sonar-runner I had created modules for C++ part of code in the sonar-project.properties file, but now after migrating to MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner, I dont know how to give module information since there is no sonar-project.properties file. Can anyone help me if module creation at all possible using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner or not ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This new tool derives info with .sln file... It is heavily integrated thru Microsoft SonarSource collaboration. If ur solution is modular it will be taken care by itself

Comment: Hi shiva ,i understand that Msbuild sonar runner will create modules based on the .csproj mentioned in the sln , but i want to create modules inside those modules, sub-module to be precise , do you have a plan for that ? This is where i am stuck right now

Comment: Sorry I have very little idea on that. Write in sonarqube google group or tag Fabrice or Ann from Sonarsource they'd be able to address this